# Узнать, поддерживает ли устройство команду

Tags: javascript

```
screen.orientation.lock('landscape')
```

При выполнении команды на пк, возникает ошибка.
Вопрос, каким образом проверить, поддерживает ли устройство команду?

Comment: возникает, наверное, не ошибка, а исключительная ситуация, вследствие чего выбрасывается исключение, которое надо отловить?

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: screen.orientation.lock() is not available on this device.

Comment: Мне узнать, поддерживает ли устройство команду, так как необходимо выполнить еще операции при условии, что поддерживается команда.